# Sharepoint2013 ctx and Js : Retrieve the value of a field from a list

Tags: 2013, list, client-object-model, splistitem, ctx

I'm a totally beginner and totally stuck to a point in my Sharepoint project.

**What i would like to achieve:**

- part 1 : retrieve the current user's Department's name
- part 2 : retrieve the department's website's url from a custom list using ctx, and jquery. *(I'm totally new to REST, so please no REST answer)*

**Structure of the custom List:**

- name = "O Services"
- field's name i would like to retrieve from that list : "URLSitesServices"
- field's name of the department : "Service"
  So, for example, in O Services, i have an item called (field Name) "Information Service", whose URLSitesServices is "http://mysite/service".

So, on site homepage, if user's department is Information Service, i would like to go in O Services, search for the Service called "Information Service" and retrieve its URLSitesServices

**What i've already done:**

part 1 is complete, i'm able to retrieve the current user's department's name.

**i'm stuck in part 2** : i don't know how to ask for O Services, i don't know how to retrieve the different items, nor their different fields...

Here is my code so far :

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc('SP.js', 'SP.ClientContext', function() {
       SP.SOD.executeFunc('userprofile', 'SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager', function() {
           getMyProfileProperties(
              function(profileProperties){
                 var fullProperties = profileProperties.get_userProfileProperties();
                 var myDepartment = fullProperties["Department"];
                 if (myDepartment){
                    var ctx2 = new SP.ClientContext();
                    var targetList = ctx2.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Services Osiris');
                    console.log(myDepartment);
                 }else{
                    console.log("nothing");
                 }
              },
              function(sender,args){
                  console.log('Error occurred while getting user profile properties:' + args.get_message());
              }    
           );
       });
    });
```

My `targetList` does just return a array, no useful values.
i don't know how to retrieve the items, i saw `get_items()` etc.. but it does not work (i'm sure i'm making a lot of mistakes too)

**Coul you please give me some hints, some clues to begin with, please?**
Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You need to write a CAML Query to query the list. The query will try to get a result based on the department. Example:

```
var targetList = ctx2.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Services Osiris');
var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name=\'Service\'/>' + 
        '<Value Type=\'Text\'>' + myDepartment + '</Value></Eq></Where></Query><RowLimit>1</RowLimit></View>');
this.collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery); 
clientContext.load(collListItem, 'Include(URLSitesServices)');  
clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));   
function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {    
    var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();        
    while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        alert(oListItem.get_item('URLSitesServices'));
        break;
    }    
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When I was(still am) new to the client object model I too stumbled a lot. But https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj163201.aspx this link helped me a lot.
Very clear and easy to understand instructions. Take a look once.

I see that you've dived into it so you can directly skip to the code snippets.

I hope it helps.